# Is it possible to notify the user when their status has changed on a Freeform entry?

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

Is there any way to send a notification to the user once the form entry status has changed? Ideally I need around 3-4 different status'.

It would need to work so that if a status is changed to *More info* a specified notification is sent out to the user, then the same for approved, denied etc.

Is this something that can be done with FreeForm Pro?

Comment: I've managed to create a bespoke system whereby emails can be sent from the admin however if anyone has a better option I'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `{exp:freeform:edit}` (Freeform Pro feature), there is the `notify_on_edit=""` parameter that you can use.

From the [documentation](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/edit/#notify_on_edit) (http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/edit/#notify_on_edit):

> **notify_on_edit="yes"**
>   If you wish to send out notifications to admins and users with the usual parameters upon successful edit of Freeform entry, you'll need to specify this parameter with a value of **yes**. Default is **no**.

If you want this to happen from the Control Panel (when editing a Freeform entry by changing its status), that is currently not available. We recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on:
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I will submit a request shortly.